# Special characters are working everywhere but not in the controller codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, special-characters

I have a database for a restaurant.The owner will add categories such Pizza,Desert or Risotto(no accents or special characters) or categories with special characters/accents such as Salată, Pește or Vodkă(romanian characters).

The table for categories is set to accept special characters.I used `ALTER TABLE tbl_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8` for this.

In the navbar i have a dropdown with all the products(food and bar).

To access one category i'm using `GET` like this:

```
<?php foreach ($categories_bar as $category): ?>
       <a class="dropdown-item" href="<?php echo site_url('/bar/'.implode('_',explode(" ",$category['category_name']))); ?>"><?php echo $category['category_name']; ?></a>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Using this, the `URL` will be http://localhost/quartiere/bar/name_of_the_category if the category name will have 2 or more words or http://localhost/quartiere/bar/nameofthecategory if the category name will contain only one word.

When the user click's on a category, the server will make this actions:

1. Get the id of the category using category name(from url)
2. Get the products with the specific category id
3. Display them on a page.

The problem is that when a category with special characters is clicked, to the database will not go the normal name...it will go something like this(for the word Pălincă)-> P%C4%83linc%C4%83.

It's strange beacuse in the dropdown the names are displayed correctly.

The function that should display the products for every category is this.At the beginning i'm reversing the explode-implde process that i'm doing in navbar.Doing this i will have a string just like the string from database:

```
public function bar_view($name = NULL){
        $name_to_pass = implode(' ',explode('_',$name));
        $category = $this->products_model->get_category_id($name_to_pass);
        $products = $this->products_model->get_bar_prods_by_category($category);

        $data['title'] = $name_to_pass;
        $data['products'] = $products;

        if(empty($data['products'])){
            show_404();
        }
        $this->load->view('templates/header');
        $this->load->view('menu/bar_view',$data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }
```

To specify:

1. In the `head` i have `<meta charset="utf-8">`
2. In config file i have this `$config['charset'] = 'utf-8';`
3. In database file i have this `'char_set' => 'utf8'` and `'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci'`

Comment: Is `P%C4%83linc%C4%83` what you are getting in the URL bar or in the `$name` var?

Comment: $name_to_pass is `P%C4%83linc%C4%83`.The URL contains "Pălincă".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you just need:

`urldecode()`

> Decodes any %## encoding in the given string. Plus symbols ('+') are
>   decoded to a space character.

```
$name_to_pass = implode(' ',explode('_', urldecode($name)));
```

Comment: You know Sad Smile Tom Hiddleston GIF?This is me right now :))
Thank you :) 
I will mark it as an aswer

Comment: hahah happy to help ;) also if you just want to replace spaces with underscores or underscores with spaces it might be a good idea to use `str_replace` it is faster than exploding then imploding! also often I see so many questions lacking the info needed to understand the full issue, yours was not the case: keep it up!

Comment: God...i'm working from october in php and i didn't learned all this fucntions >.>  ty very much